# Does LTE require a special modem from WiMAX or just a firmware upgrade?

Tags: 4g, htc-evo-3d

Sprint has talks of starting LTE data, but for now all their 4g phones support WiMAX.

I am considering starting a sprint unlimited contract with the EVO 3D phone.

The phone supports WiMAX 4g, on a snapdragon msm8660 processor. I'm wondering if this phone will be able to support LTE if sprint does release it, or does LTE require a special modem?

Answer (score 3):

The HTC Evo does not contain any LTE hardware, so it wont work

Answer (score 1):

Even on Sprint, LTE will be supported through new devices, just like on all the other carriers. WiMAX is a different technology. Because they are both *called* 4G is irrelevant. HSPA+ is called 4G, too, and is also not the same as LTE (or WiMax),

Comment: Right, I get that it's a completely different protocol, I was just curious if the EVO 3d has LTE hardware, or if its CDMA or WiMax Radios can support LTE through firmware tweaks.

Comment: The technologies are on different frequencies; the filters used in the radios are all hardware and so you can't tweak it through firmware.